Cannot query entity [Coupon] on non-existent property: Id
Compilation failure
Unable to implement Repository method: CouponRepository.findById(Object id). Cannot query entity [Coupon] on non-existent property: Id
Lombok is effective. This problem can be solved by adding get and set methods.
I was testing and found this error, it might be my problem

Please include code or better explain why you got that problem. We can't just assume how your system looks like.
